# How to build a 3D interactive world in a browser based application?

Tags: architecture, browser, 3d

I have a friend and he recently started to learn "Cinema 4D". He asked me if I could build him a website in which he could build  a3D world, or room, using a Cinema4D file, where people could visit his work. Probably by interacting with objects.

I've searched a bit in StackOverflow and I found this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196556/are-browser-based-online-games-possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196556/are-browser-based-online-games-possible.).

It gave me some ideas, but that's not exactly the same thing. My question is. Is this application possible? Can I build such a website, using his Cinema4D files, allowing people to interact the website application like in a 3D game? Would this be possible with Silverlight (.NET is the technology where I feel more comfortable)? Probably with XNA port to Silverlight? I don't know... Does anyone of you could give an advice on how to architect and build this? I need some expertise (at least greater than mine! :)) from you guys.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Not really related but still pretty cool. http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/3d/  Requires a browser that supports <canvas>

Comment: Ah.. the old "I have a friend; It's not me..." routine. I see right through you.

Comment: If you've gotten your answer, mark it as the correct answer to be nice (so Jason gets reputation points). :)

Comment: Sorry about the "off topic". 

T Pops: About that "Ah.. the old "I have a friend; It's not me..." routine.". Yes! :D This time is for true! :p He is really my cousin! :) But the main question is still my part of the project! So, I can't skip the rookie shame by telling that old story of "I have a friend; It's not me...". ;) 

musikfreak: I'll mark it as an answer! Thanks for remembering me! ;)

Once again, thanks to everyone! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into [Unity3D](http://www.unity3d.com). They have a web plugin that allows the 3D scenes to be interacted with in a browser. I am not sure if it can import Cinema4D files directly, but i'm sure Cinema4D can export to a format that is supported.

UPDATE: Just checked Unity's manual, and it supports directly importing .c4d files.

Comment: Unity3D seems to be a solution! That's exactly what I want! Unfortunately I can't use it for free and I'm not sure it's a wise decision to spend that amount of money in such a small and non-profit project. But that's what I'm looking for! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 2):

> "Unity3D seems to be a solution! That's exactly what I want! Unfortunately I can't use it for free and I'm not sure it's a wise decision to spend that amount of money in such a small and non-profit project. But that's what I'm looking for! Thank you very much! :) – rsa Jun 30 at 20:52"

If you are looking for a free solution, I recommend checking out Google's O3D API.

See: http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/

Google defines it as, "O3D is an open-source web API for creating rich, interactive 3D applications in the browser."

I was just recently introduced to it myself, so I can't share any war stories.  I do find the API intuitive and have not run into anything that completely turns me off.

Best of luck with you projects.

Comment: Hi!

Thanks! :) I'll take a look! Right now I'm already looking at the "Hello, Cube" sample code (here: http://code.google.com/intl/pt-PT/apis/o3d/docs/prettyhellocube.html). Once again, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Not "true" 3D (so no Cinema4D support, unfortunately), but there is a Flash-based 3D engine called [Alternativa3D](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/) that you might want to check out, if you have any experience with Adobe Flash. There are some demos [here](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/alternativa3d/).

Comment: In what way is that not "true" 3d? How do you define the "trueness" of a 3d solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a look at this site?

[Aether3D.com](http://aether3d.com)

It allows you to upload your models in W3D format (cinema 4d exports to w3d) and explore them through a browser.

If you need more information look here Aether3D.com/info.php or mail me

Aether3d.com is a small project I was working on last summer. 
It's still quite buggy but if someone finds it useful I'll try to finish it ;-)
The technology I used is Shokwave3d so you might need to install the plugin to view the examples.